# opengl textures not rendering correctly

Tags: java, opengl, graphics, textures

The problem i am encountering is that i cannot get my texture to render in the correct proportions and for some reason the texture is also repeating itself with a space inbetween.

this is the texture im using(i am trzing to fill the screen with this texture):

[image: Texture]

When rendered it looks like this(red outline is the entire screen and texture is rendered with a 1 px border):

[image: screenshot]

and here is the code:

```
package game;

import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;

import org.lwjgl.input.Keyboard;
import org.lwjgl.opengl.Display;
import org.lwjgl.opengl.DisplayMode;
import org.lwjgl.opengl.GL11;
import org.lwjgl.util.Timer;
import org.lwjgl.util.glu.GLU;
import org.newdawn.slick.opengl.TextureLoader;

public class WarZone {

private boolean done = false;
private String windowTitle = "War Zone";
private DisplayMode displayMode;
private Timer timer;
private float dt;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    new WarZone().run(false);
}

public void run(boolean fullscreen) {
    try {
        init();
        switchToOrtho();
        while (!done) {
            timer.tick();
            update();
            render();
            Display.update();
        }
        cleanup();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        System.exit(0);
    }
}

private void update() {
    // Exit if Escape is pressed or window is closed
    if (Keyboard.isKeyDown(Keyboard.KEY_ESCAPE) || Display.isCloseRequested()) {
        done = true;
        return;
    }
}

private boolean render() {
    GL11.glClear(GL11.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL11.GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);  // Clear the screen and the depth buffer
    GL11.glLoadIdentity();                                              // Reset the current modelview matrix

    int w = displayMode.getWidth();
    int h = displayMode.getHeight();

    GL11.glColor3f(1, 0, 0);
    GL11.glBindTexture(GL11.GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0);
    GL11.glBegin(GL11.GL_QUADS);
        GL11.glVertex2i(0, 0);
        GL11.glVertex2i(w, 0);
        GL11.glVertex2i(w, h);
        GL11.glVertex2i(0, h);
    GL11.glEnd();
    //if(true)return false;
    GL11.glColor3f(0, 1, 1);
    GL11.glBindTexture(GL11.GL_TEXTURE_2D, 1);
    GL11.glBegin(GL11.GL_QUADS);
        GL11.glTexCoord2f(0, 0);
        GL11.glVertex2i(1, 1);
        GL11.glTexCoord2f(1, 0);
        GL11.glVertex2i(w - 1, 1);
        GL11.glTexCoord2f(1, 1);
        GL11.glVertex2i(w - 1, h - 1);
        GL11.glTexCoord2f(0, 1);
        GL11.glVertex2i(1, h - 1);
    GL11.glEnd();

    return true;                                                        // Rendered correctly
}

public static void switchToOrtho() {
    GL11.glDisable(GL11.GL_DEPTH_TEST);
    GL11.glDisable(GL11.GL_LIGHTING);
    GL11.glMatrixMode(GL11.GL_PROJECTION);
    GL11.glPushMatrix();
    GL11.glLoadIdentity();
    GL11.glOrtho(0, Display.getDisplayMode().getWidth(), 0, Display.getDisplayMode().getHeight(), -1, 1);
    GL11.glMatrixMode(GL11.GL_MODELVIEW);
    GL11.glLoadIdentity();
}

public static void switchToFrustum() {
    GL11.glEnable(GL11.GL_DEPTH_TEST);
    GL11.glEnable(GL11.GL_LIGHTING);
    GL11.glMatrixMode(GL11.GL_PROJECTION);
    GL11.glPopMatrix();
    GL11.glMatrixMode(GL11.GL_MODELVIEW);
}

private void init() throws Exception {
    createWindow();
    initGL();
    load();
}

private void load() throws FileNotFoundException, IOException {
    TextureLoader.getTexture("BMP", new FileInputStream("res/temp/Main_Menu_Play_Button.bmp"), true).getTextureID();
}

private void createWindow() throws Exception {
    DisplayMode availibleDisplayModes[] = Display.getAvailableDisplayModes();
    for (DisplayMode d:availibleDisplayModes) {
        if (d.getWidth() == 640 && d.getHeight() == 480 && d.getBitsPerPixel() == 32) {
            displayMode = d;
            break;
        }
    }
    Display.setDisplayMode(displayMode);
    Display.setTitle(windowTitle);
    Display.create();
}

private void initGL() {
    GL11.glEnable(GL11.GL_TEXTURE_2D);          // Enable texture mapping
    GL11.glShadeModel(GL11.GL_SMOOTH);          // Enable smooth shading
    GL11.glClearColor(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);  // Black background
    GL11.glClearDepth(1.0f);                    // Depth buffer setup
    GL11.glEnable(GL11.GL_DEPTH_TEST);          // Enables depth testing
    GL11.glDepthFunc(GL11.GL_LEQUAL);           // Type of depth testing

    GL11.glMatrixMode(GL11.GL_PROJECTION);      // Select projection matrix
    GL11.glLoadIdentity();                      // Reset the projection matrix

    // Calculate the aspect ratio of the window
    GLU.gluPerspective(45.0f, (float)displayMode.getWidth() / (float)displayMode.getHeight(), 0.1f, 100.0f);
    GL11.glMatrixMode(GL11.GL_MODELVIEW);// Select the modelview matrix
    GL11.glHint(GL11.GL_PERSPECTIVE_CORRECTION_HINT, GL11.GL_NICEST);// Most precise perspective calculations
}

public void requestFinish() {
    done = true;
}

private void cleanup() {
    Display.destroy();
}

}
```

I would reallz appreciate it if someone could tell me what i had done wrong.

Comment: You should keep the texture id you get from `getTextureID`, then use that when binding the texture. There is no guarantee that the first texture you create will get the texture name `1`, which is what you are always binding. Now, that's not your problem, but it's always good form, as your code may not work on other cards or drivers.

Comment: yea i know but in this case it didnt matter

Comment: Where's the code for `TextureLoader.getTexture()`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, I don't know what `TextureLoader` or `newdawn.slick.opengl` are, so there is only limited information I can give about this.

However, it is very possible that your texture loading code does not know how to handle non-power-of-two textures. Which means it is likely padding the texture's size out to the nearest power of two.

More importantly is this:

```
GL11.glColor3f(0, 1, 1);
GL11.glBindTexture(GL11.GL_TEXTURE_2D, 1);
GL11.glBegin(GL11.GL_QUADS);
    GL11.glTexCoord2f(0, 0);
    GL11.glVertex2i(1, 1);
    GL11.glTexCoord2f(1, 0);
    GL11.glVertex2i(w - 1, 1);
    GL11.glTexCoord2f(1, 1);
    GL11.glVertex2i(w - 1, h - 1);
    GL11.glTexCoord2f(0, 1);
    GL11.glVertex2i(1, h - 1);
GL11.glEnd();
```

This will draw a screen-sized quad (assuming that `w` and `h` are screen sizes). This quad maps the *entire* area of the texture to this quad. OpenGL is only doing what you told it to do: take the texture and map it to the quad.

If you want to draw a texture with pixel accuracy (1:1 texel to pixel), then you need to provide a width and height to the vertex positions that is equal to the *texture's* size, not the screen size.

Also, you set the color to (0, 1, 1). The default texture environment will multiply the per-vertex color by the texel values fetched from the texture. So you should either set the color to white, or change the texture environment.

Comment: I agree TextureLoader probably rescales the image. OP should try another image loading library that doesn't do this.

Answer (score 0):

OpenGL Doesn't like textures that are not powers of two if I recall. Is your texture a power of 2 for both height and width?

http://www.gamedev.net/topic/466904-opengl-textures-only-power-of-two/

Comment: thats not the case because i tried this with a different texture with even dimensions and the same thing happened

Comment: -1: OpenGL hasn't required power-of-two textures for the last five years _at least_. Yes, you need hardware that can do it, but again, any hardware released in the last five years has not had this limitation.